# Storyboard buttons wont push Seque

Tags: ios5, xcode4.2, xcode-storyboard

I know this might sound really ridiculas but all of a sudden when I link up screens using storyboard: right click drag> push> The link is created in storyboard, but no nav bar is entered on the screen, and the button doesn't work when run in simulator? Ive re booted the computer, quit xcode, its just all of a sudden happened. I really am stuck now, ive tried creating new projects and its the same in all of them.  I can navigate screens by adding them to a tab bar controller but thats it.  I  cannot get any seques to work in any project.

Anyone else experienced this that can offer some advice? Im using xcode 4.3

Comment: Just to add, modal works fine, just push is withdrawing its co operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creation of "push" segue, select your first view controller (the caller) and go to

> Editor > Embed in > Navigation Controller

Just tested and works fine

Comment: Thank you so much for this, can't tell you how frustrating it was.  So grateful to you!

Answer (score 0):

Can it be that you deleted the associated navigation controller by any chance? If so, add it again and associate it with your start view controller.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Ive  created new projects to test it, and it does the same in those, also modal works fine, its just push for some bizarre reason

Answer (score 0):

I see that the OP got a solution, but I have another solution that may help someone else.

I had the same symptom: suddenly, my button weren't working.

Check that the ViewController in the Storyboard is set to the correct viewController class. Somehow that attribute got reset in my project and the buttons stopped working.